# no type information (try :GHGReload)

Tags: haskell, vim

I'm using haskellmode, a vim plugin, and when I move my cursor over an editor window in the course of typing code, I get a message at the bottom of the window that says:

> no type information (try :GHGReload)

When I do:

```
:GHGReload
```

I get the error:

```
Not an editor command: GHGReload
```

What is that all about?  Or, alternatively, is there a better vim plugin for haskell?  I should note I get no auto indenting with haskellmode, which I find surprising.  In fact, haskellmode doesn't seem to do anything but change tabs to 8 spaces and give me that error message.

Comment: Have you considered Emacs? :P I'm actually somewhat serious with that suggestion--Emacs supports Haskell incredibly well, including good indentation. You coeven use evil mode to retain most of the vim features you're used to.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the command is `:GHCReload` not `:GHGReload`.

Comment: That seems to do something for a few seconds, then when I move my cursor over the editor window, I get:  type information may be out of date (try GHGReload). What is supposed to do?

Comment: @7stud Make sure you save the file before calling `:GHCReload`, it can't compile stuff in the buffer. I am guessing you were talking about the "mouse cursor", having it hovers on a function name would trigger `haskellmode` to show you it's type. Or you can put the command cursor over the function name and type `_t` (in normal mode) will do the same thing. What I haven't figured out is that, sometimes `_t` doesn't work, but `_si` does.

Comment: Thanks! That _t thing is the first haskelmode feature I've been exposed to.  It looks like any time after I save, :w, I get that annoying Reload message when my cursor moves over the window.  Then if I do :GHCReload, I see a message that says: "browsing module Main" (even though my module is not named Main), and the cursor problem goes away.  What is _si?  I tried it but I'm not sure what's going on.  And how do I get out of it?

Comment: @7stud Forgot to mention that, the document says `:make` is preferred over `:GHCReload`, which reports errors from compilation and not trash the GHCi type cache if there are errors (`:GHCReload` will always trash the cache). Also, I think the mouse cursor balloon only works in gVim, it won't show in terminal Vim since it can't do pop-ups. `_si` will show more info, e.g. which module the function is defined in, but in the vim preview window; use `:pclose` or `<CTRL-W><CTRL-Z>` to close the preview window.